# How to show loading image before Action is completed ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is an `ASP.Net MVC 5` project.

I have a simple `javascript`/`jQuery` as follow:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textBox").focusout(function () {
      var phrase= $("#textBox").val();
      phrase= phrase.replace(new RegExp(/\s+/, 'g'), "%20");
      $("#commentDiv").load("../Search/SearchSingular?phrase=" + phrase);
    });
  });
</script>
```

As you can see, there is a `jQuery` `.load` method which calls `SearchSingular` action in the `Search` controller when the focus is out from HTML element with `id = textBox`. This works well, except that the `SearchSingular` action execution may sometimes take time to finish.

Thus, I want to show a loading image when the load is not finished. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a loading image while div contents load

```
("#loadingImage").show();
$("#commentDiv").load("../Search/SearchSingular?phrase=" + phrase, function(){

  $("#loadingImage").hide(); // hide the image after loading of div completes

});
```

Div for your loading image

```
<div id="loadingImage">
 <img src="loader.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: This works really well and is the most complete yet simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Turn it into a callback

```
// Somecode to display a image

$("#commentDiv").load("../Search/SearchSingular?phrase=" + phrase, function() {
  // Somecode to remove image
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a `complete` callback of jQuery `.load` function (read more http://api.jquery.com/load/)

You could revise your javascript as following:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textBox").focusout(function () {
      var phrase= $("#textBox").val();
      phrase= phrase.replace(new RegExp(/\s+/, 'g'), "%20");
      ShowLoading();
      $("#commentDiv").load(
        "../Search/SearchSingular?phrase=" + phrase,
        function () { HideLoading(); }
      );
    });
  });
</script>
```